# Create a new Rcpp::DateVector using given dates as string

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

How can I create a new `DateVector` (a C++ class from the package [`Rcpp`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp)) with dates given during compile time?

Since a `DateVector` is an `NumericVector` I can do this:

```
DateVector d = DateVector::create(14974, 14975, 15123); // TODO how to use real dates instead?
```

But I would prefer to use a more intuitive and human-readable representation like

```
DateVector d = DateVector::create("2010-12-31", "2011-01-01", "2011-05-29");
```

but this causes an compiler error like

> Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/converter.h:34:27: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘caster::target>(const char [11])’
>       return caster(input) ;

**Edit:** I have found a working example (also showing some variations):

```
DateVector d = DateVector::create(Date("2010-12-31"), Date("01.01.2011", "%d.%m.%Y"), Date(2011, 05, 29));
```

Comment: Textual parsing of dates is done by other C++ libraries / packages and not part of Rcpp itself.  So I would write a helper function based on an existing (other) date parser.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel THX to clarify this, I wasn't sure if there is a shortcut hidden anywhere (I was looking into the source code ATM).

Comment: Of course one looks at the source. And there you see exactly two constructors: one for `SEXP` and for `int n`.  Hence no `char* / string` vectors.

Comment: A have found short example (there is none at Rcpp Gallery for `DateVector`). Is it worth a new article (I could send a pull request)?

Comment: Possibly, we could sketch it out over at the Rcpp Gallery first.  Maybe open an issue with a code snippet?  Having one each for date vector and datetime vector may make sense as C++11 should give us enough rope for simple cases.

Comment: Done, see https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-gallery/issues/118